# puddles in my concrete patio

Tags: concrete, drainage

What's the best way to even out areas of concrete patio where rain water collects into 2 large puddles? It also sits right up some against pool decking.

A crack has also formed which I tried to patch with concrete caulking.

I have been trying to find the right solution and don't really understand if I should use a self-leveling product or if it needs to be done in thin layers.[image]

Comment: Surface grinding may work out better than a leveling compound unless you plan on a coating like epoxy paint to cover the diferent colors and textures. Other than that Isherwood's answer is the next step.+

Comment: Not concerned with color just that its level and doesn't puddle. Also that it lasts. The patio is old old concrete its not super smooth or anything. Its outside of covered patio... It's the sidewalk that runs along the house next to wher the pool decking begins  and then up the side of house up thru gate to driveway.

Answer (score 1):

Self-leveling materials are usually not intended to be finished-surface products--they cure out to something rather chalky. You'd need to overlay something more durable. I suggest finding a self-leveling product that meets your needs, then overlaying quarry tile or porcelain.

If that sounds overwhelming (it's not that difficult, just time consuming), You might just have to cut out the faulty portion and have it re-poured. You may find a deal by piggybacking on someone else's project. You might get lucky and avoid trip charges, or you could split them. Concrete isn't terribly expensive--it's the workmanship you pay for.

Comment: Just wondering if product like flexseal actually works or is it bs.

Comment: Not for something that large. I'd look to something like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-LevelQuik-RS-50-lb-Self-Leveling-Underlayment-LQ50/100192482).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to level this all you want but your concrete was not installed right.  I layout a lot of pools.  Yours is extremely close to your house.  It is not normal for next to house pads to hit a pool pad this close and even if they connect 20 feet apart the solution is the same.

Your house pad (sidewalk) is poured correctly with a good downslope.

Your pool pad is also poured correctly, with a slight slope away from pool to flat.

However these pads aren't supposed to be touching.  You should have some sort of drain system in between them that weeps to a non-concrete area.  Using a channel drain here would probably be the right way to handle it.

[image]